# How to remove dual grapple to object?

Tags: pc, just-cause-2

How can I remove a dual grapple attached to an object in *Just Cause 2*?

Comment: Press the grapple button again

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is press the "grapple" button one more time.  This is <kbd>F</kbd> in the PC version, <kbd>LB</kbd> on the Xbox 360, and <kbd>L1</kbd> on the PS3.  There will be a little "thwip" sound, and the grappling hook will disconnect.